# Quick Question about Sequence Notation

Tags: notation

If $b_n = \frac{1}{2n+1}$ does the notation $b_{n+1}$ make $b_n = \frac{1}{2(n+1)+1}$ or $b_n = \frac{1}{2n+2}$?

Comment: What does this have to do with sum notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former: $b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2(n+1)+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Ask yourself what you are replacing with $n+1$ to get $b_{n+1}$?  You are replacing $n$, right?  Therefore you also replace $n$ with $n+1$ in the expression on the right hand side of the equation. This gives $b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2(n+1)+1}$ as PEV said.